# How to read httpServletResponse in the interceptor?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. And now I need to read request and response in interceptor.I use a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` replace the request in `DispatcherServlet`

```
@Component("dispatcherServlet")
public class FofDisPatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        MultiReadHttpServletRequest requestWrapper = null;
        try {
            requestWrapper = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest(request);
            super.doDispatch(requestWrapper, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.doDispatch(request,response);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my interceptor , I can read the request body. But when I want to read the response body, it doesn't works.when I replace the response in the `CustomerDispatcherServlet` I got nothing response.I have tried `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` , but I got the payload with "".

It's a old question.and I have search some questions but didn't find a suitable solution.

I know I can solve the problem with `AOP`.But I want to know how can I do it in the interceptor?

---

here is my interceptor code

```
public class CustomerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    @Override
    public void postHandle(...){
        MultiReadHttpServletRequest req = (MultiReadHttpServletRequest) request;
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper res = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        Byte[] body = res. getContentAsByteArray();
        ...
    }
}
```

the body I got is [].

Comment: Can you share more of your code? How did you use `ContentCachingResponseWrapper `? As javadoc says you should call `getContentAsByteArray()` method on it to retrieve content

Comment: Yes,I use `getContentAsByteArray()` but I get content with "".

Comment: Can you share the interceptor code, the problem is in the interceptor part.

Comment: You should wrap your response object in servlet filter, not in the interceptor.

Comment: @Leffchik But why it does not work in the interceptor.I didn't find it in the document.

Comment: You can look under the hood of `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`. As java doc says it caches all content written to the `getOutputStream()` output stream. But if you wont wrap you response in servlet filter - your controller response will be written into different response `getOutputStream()` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days .I find the answer.In the `CustomerDispatcherServlet` I should add `responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse()`

the `CustomerDIspatcherServlet` like this:

```
@Component("dispatcherServlet")
public class FofDisPatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        MultiReadHttpServletRequest requestWrapper = null;
        try {
            requestWrapper = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest(request);
            if (!(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
                ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
                super.doDispatch(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
                responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
            }else {
                super.doDispatch(requestWrapper, response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.doDispatch(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Component("dispatcherServlet")
public class FofDisPatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        MultiReadHttpServletRequest requestWrapper = null;
        try {
            requestWrapper = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest(request);
            super.doDispatch(requestWrapper, new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(request));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.doDispatch(request,response);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class CustomerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    @Override
    public void postHandle(..., HttpServletResponse response){
        if (response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper) {
            Byte[] body = ((ContentCachingResponseWrapper)response). getContentAsByteArray();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your code

```
public class CustomerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    @Override
    public void postHandle((HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView){
        MultiReadHttpServletRequest req = (MultiReadHttpServletRequest) request;
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper res = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        Byte[] body = res. getContentAsByteArray();
        ...
    }
}
```

You are passing request in ContentCachingResponseWrapper.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935190/contentcachingresponsewrapper-produces-empty-response) question very similar problem .

Comment: Oh,In my code ,I use response.in the question I write wrong,sorry.