# Need to get the actual response content from HttpServletResponse in afterCompletion method in Spring HandlerInterceptor

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, interceptor

I want to get the actual content of the response as a string from HttpServletResponse object in afterCompletion method in my Spring interceptor.

Note: I need to get this in Interceptor only, not using Filters. Any options available ?

```
@Component
public class RestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

         // Need to get the actual response content here from HttpServletResponse
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and copy the HTTP servlet response output stream content for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-read-and-copy-the-http-servlet-response-output-stream-content-for-logging)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read httpServletResponse in the interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879552/how-to-read-httpservletresponse-in-the-interceptor)

Comment: Didn't help any fo them. I need to get the response body content in Interceptor, not in filter. In filter i am able to get it, but i need it in interceptor.

Comment: I looked all over the places for exactly this. But no luck. How did you solve this @somu

Comment: try use implementation from question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220192/how-to-get-response-from-httpservletresponse-and-save-to-database-in-java-via-in